# Should Data directories of cassandra cluster nodes be identical?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.1

Let's say I have a 2 node cluster where all the nodes have identical **data_file_directories** (with say 3 folder) configured in cassandra.yaml
For example

```
data_file_directories:
    - E:/Cassandra/data/var/lib/cassandra/data
    - K:/Cassandra/data/var/lib/cassandra/data
    - F:/Cassandra/data/var/lib/cassandra/data
```

Now let's say I add a 3rd node to cluster with different data_file_directories (with say 1 folder)

```
 data_file_directories:
    - B:/Cassandra/data/var/lib/cassandra/data
```

Is it incorrect to do so ? During re-balance of data, will data from 3 directories of existing node flow to 1 directory of new node ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nate McCall (the current Apache Cassandra Project Chair) answered a similar question here: [How does cassandra split keyspace data when multiple directories are configured?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15925549/how-does-cassandra-split-keyspace-data-when-multiple-directories-are-configured/22273466#22273466)

In short, this should be fine.  Cassandra spreads the data across the entries in `data_file_directories` evenly, regardless of how many are there.  Additionally, the number of tokens that a node is responsible for is independent of this setting, so you shouldn't see any hot-spots or unbalancing (at least not due to this).

That being said, I'll add the following points:

- Specifying multiple data directories can help if they are different physical mount points.  That way if one disk should fill-up or fail unexpectedly, the node can still keep running.
- If I was planning on adding a node and keeping all of them for the long-term, I would specify the config of the new node as close as I could to the original nodes.  This especially helps in a big environment when you are responsible for multiple nodes and clusters, to not have to remember how/why one particular node in a cluster is different should you need to troubleshoot.
- The exception to the last point, would be if I had decided to move to a single data directory going forward.  But then I'd also have a plan to decommission the existing nodes and replace them with nodes that also had a similar configuration.

**Pro-tip**: If you can, try to use an automated deployment tool like Chef or Spinnaker.  That way the config of a new node is essentially a "cookie-cutter" of all the other nodes in your cluster.